# C# WSDL returns XML Response but variable is still null

Tags: c#, xml, wsdl

I have a WSDL that returns an Xml Response but when I try and assign it to the response variable the object remains null.

This is my code calling the web service and attempting to assign the response to my variable:

```
CustomerReq request = new CustomerReq();
            request.DayPhone = "";
            request.OrganizationCode = "JY-US";
            request.EmailID = "sampleemail@se.com";

            getCustomerInfoResponse response = new getCustomerInfoResponse();


            WSA_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP_OMSClient client = new WSA_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP_OMSClient();
            client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new FaultFormatingBehavior());

            client.Open();

            response.getCustomerInfoResponse1 = client.getCustomerInfo(request);
            client.Close();
```

This is the Xml request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005    /05/addressing/none">http://WSA_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP_OMS/getCustomerInfo</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<getCustomerInfo OrganizationCode="JY-US" DayPhone="" EmailID="sampleemail@se.com" xmlns="http://WSA_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP_OMS" />
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And the response I receive:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
<soapenv:Body>
<out:getCustomerInfoResponse xmlns:out="http://WSA_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP_OMS">
<CustomerList TotalNumberOfRecords="1">
<Customer AssignedReps="0" BuyerOrganizationCode="" CanConsumeSupplementalCapacity="N" Createprogid="SterlingHttpTester" Createts="2015-03-04T10:09:49-06:00" Createuserid="CustomerName" CustomerID="100207932" CustomerKey="20150304100950117737467" CustomerType="02" ExternalCustomerID="" Lockid="113" MaxAssignRepsOrTeams="0" MaxModifyTS="2018-04-20T15:36:41-05:00" Modifyprogid=".YRCApp" Modifyts="2018-04-20T15:36:41-05:00" Modifyuserid="CustomerName" OrganizationCode="JY-US" RegisteredDate="2015-03-04T10:09:49-06:00" RootCustomerKey="20150304100950117737467" SendsAsn="N" SendsCommitment="N" SendsFuncAck="N" SlotPreferenceType="NONE" Status="10">
<Extn ExtnAccountAllowed="N" ExtnCustomerCreditRating="N" ExtnCustomerCrossRefItem="N" ExtnDirectMailFlag="Y" ExtnEmplFeed="N" ExtnLastOrdDate="2017-10-13" ExtnPayrollDeductionAllowed="N" ExtnPrepayAllowed="N" ExtnRequiredPONumber="N" ExtnShipComplete="N" ExtnShipToEmpl="N" ExtnSubscrStatus="0" ExtnTotCustValue="0.00" ExtnTotalOrders="0" ExtnWebAccountAllowed="N" ExtnWebCustomerID="CustomerName@genesco.com" ExtnWebEnabled="N" ExtnWebPrepayAllowed="N">
</Extn>
<CustomerContactList>
<CustomerContact Company="" Createprogid="SterlingHttpTester" Createts="2015-03-04T10:09:49-06:00" Createuserid="CustomerName" CustomerContactID="100208103" CustomerContactKey="20150304100950117737468" CustomerKey="20150304100950117737467" DayFaxNo="" DayPhone="5555555555" EmailID="CustomerName@genesco.com" EveningFaxNo="" EveningPhone="" FirstName="A" LastName="T" Lockid="3" MiddleName="" MobilePhone="" Modifyprogid="CreateOrder" Modifyts="2017-04-26T08:25:08-05:00" Modifyuserid="CreateOrder" Title="" UserID="">
<CustomerAdditionalAddressList>
<CustomerAdditionalAddress AddressType="" Createprogid="SterlingHttpTester" Createts="2015-03-04T10:09:50-06:00" Createuserid="CustomerName" CustomerAdditionalAddressID="100238485" CustomerAdditionalAddressKey="20150304100950117737470" CustomerContactKey="20150304100950117737468" CustomerKey="20150304100950117737467" IsBillTo="Y" IsDefaultBillTo="Y" IsDefaultShipTo="Y" IsInherited="N" IsShipTo="Y" Lockid="4" Modifyprogid="CreateOrder" Modifyts="2017-04-26T14:48:05-05:00" Modifyuserid="CreateOrder" PersonInfoKey="20170426082509190364347">
<PersonInfo AddressLine1="1415 Rd Pike" AddressLine2="" AddressLine3="" AddressLine4="" AddressLine5="" AddressLine6="" AlternateEmailID="" Beeper="" City="SomeCity" Company="" Country="US" Createprogid="CreateOrder" Createts="2017-04-26T08:25:08-05:00" Createuserid="CreateOrder" DayFaxNo="" DayPhone="5555555555" Department="" EMailID="CustomerName@genesco.com" ErrorTxt="" EveningFaxNo="" EveningPhone="" FirstName="A" HttpUrl="" JobTitle="" LastName="T" Lockid="0" MiddleName="" MobilePhone="" Modifyprogid="CreateOrder" Modifyts="2017-04-26T08:25:08-05:00" Modifyuserid="CreateOrder" OtherPhone="" PersonID="" PersonInfoKey="20170426082509190364347" PreferredShipAddress="" ShortZipCode="37217" State="TN" Suffix="" Title="" UseCount="0" VerificationStatus="" ZipCode="37217" isHistory="N">
<Extn ExtnNormAddLine1="1415 Rd PIKE" ExtnNormCity="SomeCity" ExtnNormState="TN" ExtnNormZipCode="#####">
</Extn>
</PersonInfo>
</CustomerAdditionalAddress>
</CustomerAdditionalAddressList>
</CustomerContact>
</CustomerContactList>
<CustomerPaymentMethodList>
<CustomerPaymentMethod AvailableAccountBalance="0" Createprogid=".YRCApp" Createts="2015-05-11T14:24:27-05:00" Createuserid="CustomerName" CreditCardExpDate="" CreditCardName="" CreditCardNo=" " CreditCardType="" CustomerAccountNo=" " CustomerContactKey="" CustomerKey="20150304100950117737467" CustomerPaymentMethodKey="20150511142427123647013" DisplayCreditCardNo="" DisplayCustomerAccountNo="" DisplayPaymentReference1="4444" DisplayPrimaryAccountNo="4444" FirstName="" IsDefaultMethod="N" IsInherited="N" LastName="" Lockid="0" MiddleName="" Modifyprogid=".YRCApp" Modifyts="2015-05-11T14:24:27-05:00" Modifyuserid="CustomerName" PaymentReference1="4444" PaymentReference2="60.0" PaymentReference3="" PaymentType="CHECK" PaymentTypeGroup="OTHER" PrimaryAccountNo="4444">
</CustomerPaymentMethod>
</CustomerPaymentMethodList>
</Customer>
<Customer AssignedReps="0" BuyerOrganizationCode="" CanConsumeSupplementalCapacity="N" Createprogid=".YRCApp" Createts="2018-08-03T07:15:00-05:00" Createuserid="CustomerName" CustomerID="100272221" CustomerKey="20180803071500281776624" CustomerType="02" ExternalCustomerID="" Lockid="0" MaxAssignRepsOrTeams="0" MaxModifyTS="2018-08-03T07:15:00-05:00" Modifyprogid=".YRCApp" Modifyts="2018-08-03T07:15:00-05:00" Modifyuserid="CustomerName" OrganizationCode="JY-US" RegisteredDate="2018-08-03T07:15:00-05:00" RootCustomerKey="20180803071500281776624" SendsAsn="N" SendsCommitment="N" SendsFuncAck="N" SlotPreferenceType="NONE" Status="10">
<Extn ExtnAccountAllowed="N" ExtnCustomerCreditRating="N" ExtnCustomerCrossRefItem="N" ExtnDirectMailFlag="N" ExtnEmplFeed="N" ExtnPayrollDeductionAllowed="N" ExtnPrepayAllowed="N" ExtnRequiredPONumber="N" ExtnShipComplete="N" ExtnShipToEmpl="N" ExtnSubscrStatus="0" ExtnTotCustValue="0.00" ExtnTotalOrders="0" ExtnWebAccountAllowed="N" ExtnWebEnabled="N" ExtnWebPrepayAllowed="N">
</Extn>
<CustomerContactList>
<CustomerContact Company="" Createprogid=".YRCApp" Createts="2018-08-03T07:15:00-05:00" Createuserid="CustomerName" CustomerContactID="100272403" CustomerContactKey="20180803071501281776625" CustomerKey="20180803071500281776624" DayFaxNo="" DayPhone="5555555555" EmailID="CustomerName@genesco.com" EveningFaxNo="" EveningPhone="" FirstName="Amber" LastName="T" Lockid="0" MiddleName="" MobilePhone="" Modifyprogid=".YRCApp" Modifyts="2018-08-03T07:15:00-05:00" Modifyuserid="CustomerName" Title="" UserID="">
<CustomerAdditionalAddressList>
<CustomerAdditionalAddress AddressType="" Createprogid=".YRCApp" Createts="2018-08-03T07:15:00-05:00" Createuserid="CustomerName" CustomerAdditionalAddressID="100318471" CustomerAdditionalAddressKey="20180803071501281776627" CustomerContactKey="20180803071501281776625" CustomerKey="20180803071500281776624" IsBillTo="Y" IsDefaultBillTo="Y" IsDefaultShipTo="Y" IsInherited="N" IsShipTo="Y" Lockid="0" Modifyprogid=".YRCApp" Modifyts="2018-08-03T07:15:00-05:00" Modifyuserid="CustomerName" PersonInfoKey="20180803071501281776626">
<PersonInfo AddressLine1="#### Rd Pike" AddressLine2="" AddressLine3="" AddressLine4="" AddressLine5="" AddressLine6="" AlternateEmailID="" Beeper="" City="SomeCity" Company="" Country="US" Createprogid=".YRCApp" Createts="2018-08-03T07:15:00-05:00" Createuserid="CustomerName" DayFaxNo="" DayPhone="5555555555" Department="" EMailID="CustomerName@genesco.com" ErrorTxt="" EveningFaxNo="" EveningPhone="" FirstName="Amber" HttpUrl="" IsCommercialAddress="N" JobTitle="" LastName="T" Lockid="0" MiddleName="" MobilePhone="" Modifyprogid=".YRCApp" Modifyts="2018-08-03T07:15:00-05:00" Modifyuserid="CustomerName" OtherPhone="" PersonID="" PersonInfoKey="20180803071501281776626" PreferredShipAddress="" ShortZipCode="37217" State="TN" Suffix="" Title="" UseCount="0" VerificationStatus="" ZipCode="37217-2829" isHistory="N">
<Extn>
</Extn>
</PersonInfo>
</CustomerAdditionalAddress>
</CustomerAdditionalAddressList>
</CustomerContact>
</CustomerContactList>
<CustomerPaymentMethodList>
</CustomerPaymentMethodList>
</Customer>
</CustomerList>
</out:getCustomerInfoResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The endpoint from App.config:

```
<endpoint address="http://som2:7803/WSA_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP_OMS"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSA_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP_OMSHttpBinding"
            contract="OMSCustomerLookup.WSA_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP_OMS" name="WSA_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP_OMSHttpPort" />
```

And the definition:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class getCustomerInfoResponse {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="getCustomerInfoResponse", Namespace="http://WSA_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP_OMS", Order=0)]
    public OMSWebServicesTest.OMSCustomerLookup.CustomerResp getCustomerInfoResponse1;

    public getCustomerInfoResponse() {
    }

    public getCustomerInfoResponse(OMSWebServicesTest.OMSCustomerLookup.CustomerResp getCustomerInfoResponse1) {
        this.getCustomerInfoResponse1 = getCustomerInfoResponse1;
    }
}
```

I've tested through SOAP UI and it works correctly and the Xml response looks correct but it doesn't allow me to assign it to the response variable and it doesn't throw any errors.  Any idea on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, also let me know if I need to give any more details.

Comment: What do you get with `var foo =..` instead of `response.getCustomerInfoResponse1 = ... `?

Comment: sorry for the delay, it is given the type of CustomerResp and the attribute of CustomerList but it remains null.

Answer (score 0):

There was a schema mismatch, this has been resolved.